# Hadoop Yarn Container Output on CONSOLE

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed-computing, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop Yarn logs the stdout and stderr of container in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs/application/container/logs

Is there any better way to redirect output to console, other then opening a socket connection and redirecting the output to the socket?

Hadoop Logger service can be used to redirect stdout ??